Problem regarding writing equations for torque
I was solving the following example from Classical Mechanics by David Morins:

A string wraps around a uniform cylinder of mass $M$, which rests on a fixed plane. The string passes up over a massless pulley and is connected to a mass $m$, as shown in the following figure. Assume that the cylinder rolls without slipping on the plane, and that the string is parallel to the plane. What is the acceleration of mass $m$? What is the condition on the ration $\frac{M}{m}$ for which the cylinder accelerates down the plane?

$\hspace{70mm}$
Morins has drawn the forces as above on the cylinder, the five equations written down in the solution to the problem are
$$T - mg = ma_2$$
$$Mg\sin\theta - T - F = Ma_1$$
$$FR - TR = \left(\frac{MR^2}2\right)\alpha$$
$$\alpha = \frac{a_1}{R}$$
$$a_2 = 2a_1$$
I understood all of these equations except for the third one, it is the equation for torques on the cylinder $\tau = I\alpha$. The issue I have with the third equation is that why does the $TR$ term have a negative sign? Is it because of the direction of the cross product?
Another problem I have is in understanding the $5^{th}$ equation, it is said that the top point moves twice as fast as the center. Why though, I could not understand.
Or is there an intuitive way to understand the sign for the $TR$ term?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

$T$ is acting tangentially on the cylinder. Since $T$ is a force, we must consider the radius of the cylinder to get the torque $TR$.

So the direction comes from the right hand rule doesnt it for cross products, which is the reason for the negative sign?

Look at $T$ and $F$. They each rotate the cylinder in opposite directions. Which is positive and which is negative is up to you as long as it is consistent. We do use the right hand rule but then we must ask ourselves, which is the top of the cylinder and which is the bottom?

@JohnDouma, Thanks! Understood it now!
